# SQL query to select records that has matching substring in a field from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table like this

```
Rules (RuleValue varchar (50))
```

It has values like

```
A1B1C1
A1B1C0
A1B0C0
```

There is another table

```
Input (RulePart varchar (2))
```

It can have values like:

```
A1
B1
C1
```

I want to get all RuleValues where all the RulePart matches anywhere in the RuleValue
Following is an example with hardcoded RuleParts:

```
Select RuleValue from Rules where Rules.RuleValue like '%A1%' and Rules.RuleValue like '%B1%' and Rules.RuleValue like '%C1%'
```

With the above examples my expected result is A1B1C1 or B1A1C1 or C1A1B1 etc.

I tried to use inner join, but it does not match all the Rule Parts in every row.

I can achieve this using creating query dynamically but don't want to go for that unless it affects query performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is:

```
Select r.RuleValue 
  from Rules r
  join Input i
    on r.RuleValue like '%' + i.RulePart + '%'
 group by r.RuleValue 
having count(distinct i.RulePart) = 3     -- or (select count(*) from Input )
```

**UPDATE**
More elegant way is using `NOT EXISTS` to represent for `ALL`

```
select * 
  from Rules r
 where not exists
     (
       select * 
         from Input i
        where r.RuleValue not like '%'+i.RulePart+'%'
     )
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11984/4)</kbd>

Comment: I think your query is printing "A1B0C0" when rule part values are "A1" ,"B1" ,"C1" http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/11984/1/0

Comment: @SUDHIR...Yes, you're right, but `count(distinct i.RulePart)` can fix the problem.

Comment: If I have only two RulePart A1 and B1 than the answer should be all RuleValues having A1 and B1, your first answer was not returning expected result in above condition, the second answer is giving expected results.

Comment: If so, replace `3` to `(select count(*) from Input )` in the first query.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * 
FROM Rules a
WHERE RuleValue LIKE '%'+(SELECT stuff((select '%' + cast(c.RulePart as varchar(512))from Input c for xml path('')),1,2,''))+'%'`

Comment: example if you dont like joins :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is [sqlfiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/374e5/4/0).

```
SELECT * FROM Rules r
INNER JOIN Input n 
ON
substring(r.RuleValue,1,2) = n.RulePart
OR
substring(r.RuleValue,3,2) = n.RulePart
OR
substring(r.RuleValue,5,2) = n.RulePart
```

Comment: your answer has hardcoded input length and search area in RuleValue, I am expecting answer which can search anywhere in RuleValue for any RulePart of any length.